# Coded UI test as part of gated check-in

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfsbuild, coded-ui-tests

I have coded UI tests running locally just fine, because I can open up IE and point the window at localhost.  When I attempt to run these tests on the build server, they fail because the window isn't open yet.  How can I get an instance of IE open on the build server as part of these tests, for these tests to run against?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving interactive logon permission to your account underwhich build is running...